# Sections in the separate background color

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am working on a project which is to be able to insert a table of 3 boxes with a number, a status and an image

I display these 3 elements without problem.
But when I want to put a background color css, it separates into several and sections and therefore does not take into account the entire line to apply a background.
Also the space between each is minimal

This is what my code does:
[image: WHAT MY CODE DO]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/commandes.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="TABLELEFT">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "BaseDeDonnées.php",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
            },
            success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                var data = response;
                let html = "";
                html += '<table>';
                
                data.forEach(element => {
                    
                    let etat_cmd;
                    let commande;
                    let num_cmd;

                     if (element['enc_ext_ref'] != null) {
                        num_cmd = '#'+element["enc_ext_ref"];
                    }
                    else {
                        num_cmd = element["enc_cmd_num"];
                    }

                    if (element['enc_paye'] == 0) {
                        etat_cmd = '<span class="ATTENTE">ATTENTE REGLEMENT</span>';
                    } else {
                        switch (element['enc_prepared']) {
                            case '0':
                                etat_cmd = '<span class="ENPREPA">EN PREPARATION</span>';
                                break;
                            case '1':
                                etat_cmd = '<span class="PRETE">COMMANDE PRETE</span>';
                                break;
                        }
                    }


                    switch (element['enc_type']) {
                        case '0':
                            commande = '<span class="EMPORTER">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/nourriture.png" id="EMP"></span>';
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            commande = '<span class="LIVRAISON">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/livreurscoot.png" id="LIV"></span>';
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            commande = '<span class="SURPLACE">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/resto.png" id="TABLE"></span>';
                            break;
                    }
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + num_cmd + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + etat_cmd + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + commande + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                })

                html += '</table>';
                document.getElementById('AffichageCommandes').innerHTML = html;
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});


    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="AffichageCommandes"></div>
</body>


`


`#TABLE{
max-width: 25%;
}

#EMP{
max-width: 25%;

}

#LIV{
max-width: 25%;
}

.ENPREPA{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #FF8C01;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.PRETE{
    font-size: 33px;
    color:#05750D;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation-duration: .6s;
    animation-name: clignoter;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transition: none;

}

.ATTENTE{
    font-size: 33px;
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;

}

@keyframes clignoter {
  0%   { color:#000000; }
  40%   {color:#F1A200; }
  100% { opacity:#000000; }
}


.TABLELEFT{
    font-size: 35px;
    column-count: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 50px;


}


table td , table tr{
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #212121;
    border-radius: 13px;
}
```

Thanks to you for your help!

Comment: To colour the whole row easily, apply the CSS class to the `<tr>`

Comment: @ADyson I.e. make a tr in css with a background color as instruction ? Because I already tried it but without result ;(

Comment: New day, new nickname ...? This is still the same question that you - only "not" you, but of course we all know it _was_ you - already asked yesterday, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75580789/1427878

Comment: And you could not even be bothered to fix the structural issues you were already told about yesterday, by now.

Comment: to style the entire table row typically do `tr > td{/* css styles */}`

Comment: Please read [mcve].  Rather than just *dump* your code which includes an ajax call and html built via js - provide the *final rendered* HTML.   Then hopefully, we can see the issue *in action* - not from some random cropped screenshot that's hard to see what the issue is based on the description.

Comment: `I already tried it but without result`...you'd need to show exactly what you tried, then we can identify the issue you encountered. Because it's certainly possible to make that work.

Comment: @CBroe I lost the login information for my other account.
Regarding the validator, I don't see how my code is a problem.

Comment: `I lost the login information`....surely you know your email address, or you have a sign-up email to hand. And you can reset your password. There's no need to create multiple accounts, and indeed it would be contrary to the policy of the site.

Comment: If the AJAX function is correctly rendering your HTML and it is merely an issue of CSS please add the rendered HTML ( ie: inspect the document and copy the outerHTML of whatever parent element )  and all the css.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I agree with you.
It's at the css level when I apply the condition to put a color in the background that it doesn't work. That's where I think my mistake comes from

Comment: It could be. But unless you show us what you did when you tried to apply it to the whole row, we can't be sure if that was your mistake. Remember you can [edit] your post.

Comment: *But when I want to put a background color css* - put background colour *where*?    On a class like `PRETE`?  Or on the `tr`?  There appears to be no attempt to put a class/style on the `tr` so (obviously? logically) the style won't apply to the whole row if you only apply to a span within that row.

Comment: Possibly offtopic: Note that dark gray on ... dark gray... is not exactly easy to see.

Comment: @freedomn-m There are three classes but my wish would be to put a background color similar to the three without them being separated

Comment: So you would change `html += '<tr>';` to `html += '<tr class=' + requiredClass' + '>';`  then determine requiredClass and the css that goes with it.

Comment: Trying to understand exactly the problem - I think you have created a table and if you color the background of a tr you find that in between the columns, the color does not apply. Is that correct? If so, how about replacing all that (irrelevant) code in your question with a simple HTML table which demonstrates the problem - much easier for us to help then. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You have brought up two problems: the background coloring of the tr does not color the bits in between the td cells and there isn't enough spacing between the cells.

This snippet has the simplest possible table as an example and does two things: sets border setting to collapse and adds padding left and right to each of the cells.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

tr {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```